# Definite integral of a differential : $\int_{a}^{b} dy$ ( More generally: variables of integration versus differentials)

Tags: integration, infinitesimals

Suppose that $y$ is a function of a variable $x$ ( shortly : $y=f(x)$) ; in that case $ dy = f'(x) dx $ ( this is just the definition of a differential).

With this definition in hand,  I try to integrate $dy$ from $x=a$ to $x=b$.

$\int_{a}^{b} dy$

$= \int_{a}^{b} f'(x)dx$

$= f(b)-f(a)$. ( By the Fundamental Theorem Of Calculus)

But maybe should I have treated $dx$ also as a differential : $dx= [x]'\Delta x = (1) \Delta x = \Delta x$.  In that case, should not the answer be different?

$\int_{a}^{b} dy$

$= \int_{a}^{b} f'(x)dx$

$ = \int_{a}^{b} f'(x) . \Delta x$

$ = \Delta x \int_{a}^{b} f'(x)$

$ = (b-a) [ f(b)-f(a)]$.

So my question is: are we allowed to treat variables of integration symbols as differentials?

Comment: $\int\limits_a^b f'(x)$ has no meaning.

Comment: If I am correct, the reason is that the expression does not  contain any variable of integration? But in that case  what is the variable of integration in the first expression:  $\int_{a}^{b} dy$?

Comment: Variable is $y$ with limits $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.

Comment: @Herb Steinberg. Thanks !

Comment: In case you are interested, you can have a look at non standard Analysis. It will explain you what infinitesimals actually are and how to use them.